# find $\frac{\partial z }{\partial x}$ of $\tan(xy) + \tan(xz) + \tan(yz)$

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

> Find $\frac{\partial z }{\partial x}$ of $\tan(xy)+\tan(xz)+\tan(yz)=0$

$$\frac{\partial z }{\partial x}\tan(xy)+\frac{\partial z }{\partial x}\tan(xz)+\frac{\partial z }{\partial x}\tan(yz)=0\rightarrow y\sec^2(xy)+\sec^2(xz)(z+\frac{\partial z }{\partial x}x)+\sec^2(yz)y\frac{\partial z }{\partial x}=0$$

$$y\sec^2(xy)+z\sec^2(xz)+x\sec^2(xz)\frac{\partial z }{\partial x}+y\sec^2(yz)\frac{\partial z }{\partial x}=0$$

$$\frac{\partial z }{\partial x}(x\sec^2(xz)+y\sec^2(yz))=-z\sec^2(xz)-y\sec^2(xy)$$

$$\frac{\partial z }{\partial x}=\frac{-z\sec^2(xz)-y\sec^2(xy)}{x\sec^2(xz)+y\sec^2(yz)}$$

Is the following correct?

Comment: Edited that answer

Comment: I don't understand your notation...

Comment: @goblin it is a implicit differentiation, I should have mention it?

Comment: well you've got $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x},$ which represents a function of $x$, multiplying a boolean, namely $\tan(xy)+\tan(xz)+\tan(yz)=0.$ I don't think many people will understand what you mean here; I certainly don't.

Comment: @goblin Now the notation is ok? sorry, for misleading

Comment: It seems a little better now.

Comment: Assuming that x and y are independent variables, this looks good.